# Publishing a NuGet package to an organization feed from yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-yaml

Having trouble publishing a NuGet package from a yaml pipeline, restore/build/pack all works ok it's just the pushing that is failing and it seems to be related to the Push generating a bad url for the Artefact feed that I am pushing the package to.

I've been able to push the package from a NuGet command locally and connect to the Artefact feed, the "d____i" is an organization scoped feed and the library is in that feed as you can see, the url seems incorrect to what I get when I go to the "Connect to feed" from the DevOps page, which looks like this below

```
<add key="d_____i" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/d_____i/_packaging/d_____i/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

[image: Push failture]
[image: yaml pipeline settings for push]

I'm actually back here again because I had a long break working on some other stuff but now I am back to having to publish my packages to a feed and I'm still running into the same issue.

Different projects but essentially the same issue.

I've given the source project Build Service COntributor access to the target project scoped feed and that didn't work.

I've tried a custom nuget.config but I get 401 errors.

Just strugging with this so bad, I have decided to create a support ticket with Microsoft because I can't believe this is so hard, I'm sure it's not but it's driving me crazy and I'm simply can't move forward now.

Here is my pipeline

[image]

Everything works apart from the last step and I get the following error

> error: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dorsavi/f021750e-bf44-48e3-8892-3afd18dcddca/_packaging/bf8fd47b-0475-41e9-80fc-8e5c23e7ff8b/nuget/v3/index.json.
> error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found - VS800075: The project with id 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/f021750e-bf44-48e3-8892-3afd18dcddca' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it. (DevOps Activity ID: 97338923-B00F-4CE5-BB79-0D6BF964864C)).

I'm still going at it, trying different configurations with the push command but so far nothing has worked, including using guids or names of projects/feeds

I'm trying to go from one project "CompanyName.Logging" this has the build pipeline and I'm trying to push to a feed which is a project scoped feed called "CompanyName.Platform" in a project called "CompanyName.Platform" both projects are in the same organization.

If I try to push to a feed called Test in "ComnpanyName.Logging" it works fine.

Comment: Could you try to use `packagesToPush` and provide path where your packages are?

Comment: I'll have a look at that and give it atry

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me your `publishVstsFeed` isn't set correctly. You would expect to see a GUID of the feed or name (I think in your case, `d_____i`) here and the path to the package in the `packagesToPush` property.

This is documented in the [task documentation for `NuGetCommand@2`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)

Example:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '99303781-4bbb-41d6-a13e-fe40603b9cb7'
    packagesToPush: 'packages/*.nupkg'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll have a look at packagesToPush, the threads I read previously didn't mention this but I'll give it a go and use the guid as well.